# Sending and receiving own classes in CORBA methods with Java

Tags: java, corba

I'm trying to find a way to get CORBA methods which can accept own classes or even a simple ArrayList as return data type or argument.

I've tried with Any and Object but got not results being an abstract class and an interface each.

I even tried to cast a a received Corba Object to ArrayList as I'm actually giving an ArrayList as parameter but got not results.

Comment: Can you show me your IDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a silly answer you might try Serializing your Java Objects into a byte array and passing them that way  to your functions then Deserializing them on the other side. Other than that my experience with Corba has always been encoding/decoding functions to IDL types. IDL is suppose to be one of the benefits of Corba: embrace it!

Comment: What should be the idl definition for a method receiving bytes array?

Comment: It is silly because you are essentially doing two Serializations and two Deserializations. You could try something like this in IDL: sequence<octet> byteArray;

Comment: Well, that's right, thought I did, and it was a great idea going for it instead of using CORBA's ´Any´ and ´Object´ classes.